# Alternative for the = sign

Tags: c++, equals

i was asked to implement a c++ code to perform the assignment x=y without the = sign and without functions. I have used the memcpy:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int x(5),y(3);
    memcpy(&x,&y,sizeof(y));
    printf("%d",x);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

any other generic solutions?

Thanks

Comment: Interview question? Homework?

Comment: `memcpy` is only guaranteed to work for POD types, so its genericity is relative.

Comment: @Mysticial My guess is interview

Comment: `memcpy` **is** a function...

Comment: By 'generic' do you mean that `x` and `y` can be any type, or are we talking about `int`?

Comment: Why not: `int y(5); int x(y);`.

Comment: Aww... I was hoping there would be a trigraph for `=`. :(

Comment: @sixlettervariables: Because that's not the assignment `x=y` but the initialization `int x = y;`

Comment: @MSalters: I don't disagree. His rules were to not use `=`, it had nothing to do with following any logic :)

Answer (score 11):

If `x` and `y` are assumed to be int:

```
while (x < y) {
    ++x;
}
while (y < x) {
    --x;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this one I like, it is really function free. But it is limited to integers.

Comment: @user1270438: integers and similar things, like some bidirectional iterators and pointers providing they're to the same container/array.  Could produce wrong results for float/double.

Answer (score 4):

I'm unsure what the `(5)` and the `(3)` signify as a C person, but if they're just integers then how about:

```
x |= y; // all bits set in y now definitely set in x
x &= y; // all bits not set in y now definitely not set in x
```

Or, as per Oli Charlesworth's comment below, if you don't want the = symbol then:

```
x or_eq y; // all bits set in y now definitely set in x
x and_eq y; // all bits not set in y now definitely not set in x
```

Comment: He did say no equals and also no functions, so I guess that rules out |= and &= as well

Comment: @JesusRamos I was kind of hoping he meant the = operator. Otherwise you can't pass `x` to anything and you can't modify it, so presumably the answer would be: it's impossible?

Comment: That's my guess as well, unless you use inline assembly.

Comment: `int x(5)` is the same as `int x = 5`, so your solution is fine.

Comment: @JesusRamos: It's ok, you could always use `or_eq` and `and_eq` instead!

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Have not seen that suggested in a while, made my day

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes oh, right, constructor syntax but on primitives? What a dunce I've been.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth good spot! I've added that to the answer and tagged it as community wiki, since it's no longer really _my_ answer.

Comment: Another silly alternative: `x xor_eq x` to clear `x` and then `x or_eq y` to copy the `y` bits.

Answer (score 1):

The following isn't terribly useful in any real context, but it at least solves the "problem" per its rules:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int y(5);
    int x(y);

    std::cout << x << " " << y << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think the question's asking for assignment to an existing variable `x`, but this is certainly worth listing for consideration....

Comment: this one is the one  i am looking for :) Great Help, Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Warning: this gets ugly... firmly in the land of fragile hackery ;-P.

An assignment to arbitrary type sometimes must invoke a function - whether assignment operator or [copy] constructor.  Placement `new` is an operator - not a function call - though it may need to pass parameters on to a constructor.  To reconstruct an object generically, you need to know it's been destructed beforehand, which does need a function call but not for the assignment - so is that allowed or not? :-)  Anyway, the idea's still broken if the reconstruction can throw, as the destructor can be called a second time on the already-destructed object.  In practice, you may be able to write the destructor to make that safe (e.g. NULL pointers after `delete`), or the constructor not to throw, but it's undefined behaviour and not truly generic (kinds of complications you could expect: the virtual dispatch pointer may have already been reverted to the base class from the destructors kicked in, virtual bases destructed etc.)....

```
T x = a, y = b;  // "background"

// hacked pseudo-assignment
x.~T(); // should make this function call though, if it exists!
new (&x)(y);  // x = y
```

---

Another bizaare approach that may or may not be accepted, depending on whether indirect function calls are allowed:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << y;
ss >> y;
```

---

More generally, the only mutating operators that don't involve the '=' sign in their typical form are placement `new`, `++` and `--`, and the alternative forms such as `xor_eq` have also been discussed in other answers, so I think that's about it....

Answer (score 0):

Oneliner, inspired by Michael Burr: `x += (y-x);`. Works for all numeric types, O(1), even `std::complex`, as well as random iterators (including pointers).